# SQL - Select with Limit fail

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, limit

Currently I'm having 12 rows in my database. 
Between adding all of them I deleted some so the ID columns aren't ascending correctly.

I'm running the following query the create pages by using SQL `$page` is a `$_GET` which is numerically (1,2,3 etc.):

```
"SELECT  *
FROM    cms_guestbook
WHERE   moderated = 'Y'
ORDER BY  id DESC
LIMIT   ". (($page - 1) * 5) . ", " . (5 * $page)
```

Add page 1 it displays correctly and when I `var_dump` this query it shows: `LIMIT 0, 5`.
Add page 2 it is doesn't display correctly. I see 7 rows (5-12), but my `var_dump` says: `LIMIT 5, 10`.

Page 3 also displays correctly row 10-12. The `var_dump` also says: `LIMIT 10, 15`.

Someone who knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: $page = ' 1; drop table cms_guestbook; -- '

Comment: I think what @Ray is trying to let you know is that your code could be subject to SQL Injection.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I'm familiar with SQL-injection. This was only a test case. I always use PDO prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIMIT takes 2 arguments - OFFSET, Number of Rows.

In your case, you would want...

```
LIMIT 0, 5
LIMIT 5, 5
LIMIT 10, 5
```

If you always wanted to return 5 rows but start at a different index each time.

Based on your question, change the LIMIT clause to

```
LIMIT   ". (($page - 1) * 5) . ", 5"
```

Check out [MySQL Select & Limit details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for more info.